# Como filtrar registros do banco de bados no .NET Core?

Tags: .net, linq

Sou novo no .NET Core e tem algumas coisas que me enrolo. Eu criei esta lista através do dbcontext usando dbset.

[image: public IEnumerable ObterTodosEmpresas() { return WebPEDContexto.Set().ToList(); }]

A lista é grande, e precisaria filtrar por um tipo de informação, ou seja, trazer todas as linhas do banco de dados, popular a lista, mas somente quando os registros tivessem o código 29 no campo TipoEmpresaID. Como faria pra retornar a lista, somente de registros nesta condição?

Comment: Olá Luiz, é importante você [edit] sua pergunta [evitando imagens para demonstrar códigos por uma série de ótimos motivos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635) e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar os métodos do Linq para fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```
return WebPEDContexto.Set<TEntity>().Where(x => x.TipoEmpresaID == 29).ToList();
```

Where é somente um dos vários métodos do linq. Recomendo a leitura desse artigo para aprimorar seus conhecimentos: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: Obrigado Jaderson, vou tentar aqui. Vou ler o artigo também.

Comment: Ótimo Luiz! Se te ajudar não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como aceita. Vai ajudar outros que tiverem a mesma dúvida que você.